# Removing specific part of a string in php/web scraping

Tags: php, html, string, dom, web-scraping

```
<div class="description">
    <span>Product Code:</span>
    " CODE"<br>
    <span>Availability:</span>
    " In Stock"
</div>
```

I'm trying to scrape a website using simple html dom library but I encountered a problem since the part I need is outside of a tag and has no id/class.

From the code above. What I need is the product code (CODE) alone.

I tried scraping through class:

```
$code=$html->find('.description')[0]->plaintext;
```

And this is what I got:

> Product Code: CODE Availability: In Stock

What I'm asking is how to remove `Product Code:` and `Availability: In Stock` so that what will be stored in my $code is CODE alone.

Note: CODE is dynamic and changes for each item. If you guys can provide me with alternative solution like another way to target HTML data without tag, id, class, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: it's an html page, which means it's a DOM **tree**. Even if you don't have an id on some specific item, you can always follow the tree branches from a known point. e.g. find the div.description node, then remove the spans that are children of that node.

Comment: yeah, thats what I'm thinking earlier but the thing is i don't know the right syntax for it. I just started scraping last week and simple html dom has limited docs.

Comment: Just try my answer and you can see what you want I have just edited the code,

Answer (score 0):

Remove the div.description child spans and you should be good to go.

**EDIT: MarcB posted this a minute before me. Good job and full credit to him.**

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm thinking earlier but the thing is i don't know the right syntax for it. I just started scraping last week and simple html dom has limited docs. I've tried $code=$item->find('.description !span')->plaintext; -returns null. I've tried $code=$item->find('.description !span')[0]->plaintext; -returns "Product Code:" only

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like !span to exclude unwanted content

give a try to .description[!span]

Comment: I've tried $code=$item->find('.description !span')->plaintext; -returns null. I've tried $code=$item->find('.description !span')[0]->plaintext; -returns "Product Code:" only.

Comment: [!span] with the [ ]

Comment: I already did $code=$item->find('.description [!span]')->plaintext; -returns null. $code=$item->find('.description')[!span]->plaintext; -returns everything.